# Unable to set autoCommitOffset to true using cloud kafka streams

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka - 1.3.3 and spring-cloud-stream with Spring Boot to connect to Kafka that comprise of typical Publisher Subscriber use case in which I want enable.auto.commit to be true.

When service go up, I can see several Kafka properties (INFO logs) being printed on console that lists all applied properties. I see value of this property as false- enable.auto.commit= false, As shown belolw:

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 100
enable.auto.commit = false
auto.offset.reset = earliest
check.crcs = true
client.id = consumer-2
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = conn-dr-group
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
```

I had read on Spring Doc that if we do not provide the property of auto commit, it is set true by default -

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/

However, The value still seems to appear false when I boot up the service.

I tried providing following property in application.properties, but still it resolves to false.

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.autoCommitOffset=true

Does anyone know how can we get value of it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.autoCommitOffset=true

That is a different property; it tells the binder to commit the offset after the listener returns normally. This is more deterministic than having the client perform the commits on its own.

The binder always resets `enable.auto.commit`; you can override it using the `...binder.configuration` property, but it's not advised.

Comment: Thanks, I could now override the property as - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.configuration.autoCommitOffset=true.

Comment: Could you please educate me on why is it not advised to override this property please?

Comment: `>If true the consumer's offset will be periodically committed in the background.`  IMO, it's better to commit the offset in a more deterministic fashion - after a record has been successfully processes.